# How to avoid Bundler Authentication Call in production for a gem only used in development group?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

We currently host a gem (custom version of rubocop) in a private Github repo for one of our rails applications. In order to successfully `bundle install` that gem, bundler needs to have credentials with read permissions to that repo. We only use this gem for local development, and so the gem is listed under the development group in our project's Gemfile:

```
group :development do
 ...

 source 'https://rubygems.pkg.github.com/<org>' do
   gem '<custom-gem>'
 end
end
```

Associated entry in Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.pkg.github.com/<org>/
  specs:
    <org>-rubocop (0.1.2)
      rubocop (= 0.77.0)
      rubocop-rails (= 2.4.0)
```

For production, we do not need this gem, however we encountered an error during the deploy phase where bundle is still asking for the credentials, even though the gem will not be in use.

This error may have manifested itself after upgrading bundler from 2.2.28 to 2.3.7, but we're not positive about that.

Is it possible to configure bundler to avoid making the authentication call for a gem that will not be in use? If we can avoid this authentication call, then we can avoid specifying sensitive credentials in our production environment, which would be a lot less work...Any bundler documentation or existing Github issue that answers this question would be greatly appreciated!

Other details:

Ruby 3.1.1

Rails 7.0.2.3

In production build, we are specifying the following command:

```
bundle config set --local without 'development test' && bundle install
```

Build Logs tipping us off to the issue:

```
Step #1 - "build-push": Authentication is required for rubygems.pkg.github.com.
Step #1 - "build-push": Please supply credentials for this source. You can do this by running:
Step #1 - "build-push": `bundle config set --global rubygems.pkg.github.com username:password`
Step #1 - "build-push": or by storing the credentials in the `BUNDLE_RUBYGEMS__PKG__GITHUB__COM`
```

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, I think your command needs to be updated to have a colon-separated list of groups to skip.

From the [Bundler Docs](https://bundler.io/v2.3/man/bundle-config.1.html#LIST-OF-AVAILABLE-KEYS%20(edited))

> without (BUNDLE_WITHOUT): A :-separated list of groups whose gems bundler should not install.

So try to update your command to the following and see what happens:

`bundle config set --local without 'development:test' && bundle install`

Comment: Unfortunately, this syntax change did not resolve the issue for me, but thanks for sharing : )

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is an all-encompassing answer to the issue, but the following changes seem to resolve the problem. I'd love to hear from anyone who might have some thoughts that might explain why this solution works or thoughts disproving my hypothesis : )

Our `Gemfile.lock` had the following entry:

```
PLATFORMS
  x86_64-darwin-21
```

Adding the following platform entry:
`bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux`

Results in a the `Platforms` entry to be updated to

```
PLATFORMS
  x86_64-darwin-21
  x86_64-linux
```

After this update, bundler seems to be respecting the gem groups and does not make an authentication request to the private repo hosting our custom gem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`BUNDLE_ONLY`](https://bundler.io/v2.3/man/bundle-config.1.html) option available with `bundler >= 2.3`

Comment: Thanks for sharing another answer! I no longer work at the org where I was having this problem, so unfortunately cannot speak to this suggestion working for the problem I was having. I do also wonder how `BUNDLE_ONLY` differs from `BUNDLE_WITHOUT`...I would expect groups specified by either option to be equally respected...

Comment: @Ciacci `BUNDLE_WITHOUT` and `BUNDLE_WITH` will always bundle the default gems (the ones outside of a group)

Comment: I don't think the behavioral difference you outlined between `BUNDLE_WITHOUT and BUNDLE_WITH` and `BUNDLE_ONLY` explains why `BUNDLE_ONLY` would work and the other options would not because the original problem I posted about involves a gem already inside a `development` group. It is not a default gem.